# Can bank accounts be locked down to prevent remote withdrawals?

Tags: bank-account, online-banking

IS it possible to secure a personal bank account so that deposits can be made remotely by somebody with the account number and sort code, but that withdrawals can only be made by somebody with direct access to the account. Such as a teller.

Comment: Have you asked your bank if they will set up an account for you that will not allow those types of withdrawals?

Comment: An account which does not allow **any** withdrawals would be pretty pointless, because even you couldn't access the money on it. Perhaps what you actually mean is an account which does not accept any **direct debit** withdrawals?

Comment: What country are we talking about?

Comment: Anywhere in the EU, and obviously there mist be some way to withdraw, I mean nothing that can be pulled out of the account.

Comment: " I don't want to give them my bank details as they use outdated systems and are a wide open target." - what are you talking about here?? the *bank* uses outdated systems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there such a thing as a deposit-only bank account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-deposit-only-bank-account)

Comment: @AakashM Here in the US, banks absolutely use outdated systems; paper checks (which are still common) contain the two numbers you need to pull money out of the account. Anyone can forge one, it's quite silly.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah yes, I always forget [that feature of the US banking system](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/cant-the-account-information-on-my-checks-be-easily-used-for-fraud)

Answer (score 5):

Your concern is that company A might be hacked in some way by company B, who would then use info they got from A to get money out of your bank account, and that your bank would declare this to be your problem? And your way of dealing with this is to try to find a special kind of account that can't be withdrawn from? Just how would you get your money out of that then?

Talk to your bank. Tell them, I have a client that wants to pay me money through BACS but I am worried that someone could misuse the details I must provide them, and I could be stolen from. Your bank, which participates in BACS transfers, can then tell you what they do to protect you in this case. They can give you the reassurance you are looking for.

Comment: If I were to tell them that I had a high risk client that would make me liable for any fraud. I'm required to not take these risks.

Comment: Where do you get that logic from? A lawyer? I don't think it's true at all.

Comment: It's in the terms and conditions.

Comment: your personal worry about someone's outdated systems does not equate to the legal definition of a high risk client. But if it did, knowing they are high risk and not telling your bank is not a strategy to reduce your risk of being liable for fraud.